# mypy incompatible return type in overriden method

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I am subclassing `UserDict` class in python 3.11, and I intend to override the `__or__` method,
When trying to do it, mypy claims that I am using an incompatible return type.
Here's an example code to recreate the error:

```
from collections import UserDict
from typing import Any, Type


class CustomDict(UserDict[str, Any]):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def __or__(self, other: Any) -> CustomDict:
        if isinstance(other, CustomDict):
            return other
        return NotImplemented
```

And when running mypy on this piece of code I get:

```
error: Return type "CustomDict" of "__or__" incompatible with return type "UserDict[Union[str, _T1], Union[Any, _T2]]" in supertype "UserDict"  [override]
```

It is unclear to me because as far as I know I can return a subclass of the superclass' method return type when overriding this method.

Comment: Why are you using `Type` there? Also it doesn't return anything in one branch.

Comment: I tried `Type[...]` `Self` and `CustomDict` as return types and none of them work. fixed the other issue you mentioned in the snippet.

Comment: "When trying to do it, mypy claims that I am using an incompatible return type." - how exactly did you determine that the complaint is about the *return type*, and not, say, the type of `other`? I don't see anything in the error message that you show, that mentions a return type. It only mentions the signature, overall.

Comment: I'm not really clear why you've typed `other` as `Any`, since according to the code `__or__` is only implemented if `other` is a `CustomDict`. Why not just write it as `def __or__(self, other: CustomDict)`?

Comment: The argument is allowed to be more general, and narrowing it doesn't fix the error.